# qtreeviewprivate.h : no such file

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview, qtreewidget, qtwidgets

I have a problem with Qt 5.5 and `QTreeView`. **qtreeview.h** (Yes, it's from Qt folder) has compiler error:

> fatal error: QTreeViewPrivate: No such file or directory.

My Qt5.5 library doesn't know about **QTreeViewPrivate**, but qtreeview.h needs it. Every simple code like this `QTreeWidget *fileList = new QTreeWidget();` or else linked to `QTreeView` makes my complier angry! Maybe it's some bug? Where is QTreeViewPrivate ?

Comment: If you are not compiling Qt you should not need private implementations. If you do I would file a bug at qt.io.

Comment: Well, I'm not compliing Qt, I'm beginer, all I wanna is to use treewidget, but this error makes me sad ( maybe I need other headers without private implementations

Answer (score 0):

Check if you added the correct library to your project file:

```
QT += widgets
```

See documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html

Comment: Yep, .pro file has it, but still no result

Answer (score 0):

Check if you added the correct Qt folder path to your project.

In project properties, c/c++ general libraries.

Comment: path is correct, other features works good, but when some .h-file links to <blabla>Private ( TreeViewPrivate, TableViewPrivate, etc.) error occurs

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the solution. To use `QTableWidget` that no need `QTableViewPrivate`'s header I edit **qtableview.h** in my Qt folder, I replased `#include <QTreeViewPrivate>` to `class QTreeViewPrivate;`. Now code works fine!